# Labeling data frame groups in R by relative position

Tags: r

I'm working with R and have a data frame looking like this:

```
Term, Course, Mark
1000, ABDC1101 ,,
1020, ABCD1101 ,,
1020, ABCD1101 ,,
1040, ABCD1101 ,*,
1040, ABCD1101 ,*,
1040, ABCD1101 ,*,
1060, ABCD1101 ,,
1020, EFGH1101 ,,
1060, EFGH1101 ,*,
```

What I'm looking for is grouping the values by Term and Course and then labeling the values depending on their position relative to the Mark "*"

```
Term, Course, Mark, Group
1000, ABDC1101 ,,   second_before
1020, ABCD1101 ,,   first_before
1020, ABCD1101 ,,   first_before
1040, ABCD1101 ,*,  base
1040, ABCD1101 ,*,  base
1040, ABCD1101 ,*,  base
1060, ABCD1101 ,,   first_after
1020, EFGH1101 ,,   first_before
1060, EFGH1101 ,*,  base
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The logic behind "labeling the values depending on their position relative to the Mark "*"" is not clear for me..

Answer (score 1):

I would offer the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
uniquerank <- function(x){
  match(x, unique(x)) 
}

df %>% 
  mutate(rown = uniquerank(Term), .by = Course) %>% 
  mutate(min_astr = min(ifelse(Mark == "*", rown, Inf)), .by = Course)%>% 
  mutate(max_astr = max(ifelse(Mark == "*", rown, -Inf)), .by = Course) %>% 
  transmute(Term,
            Course,
            Group = ifelse(Mark == "*", "base", 
                           ifelse(rown<min_astr,
                                  paste0(min_astr - rown, " before"), 
                                  paste0(rown - max_astr, " after")
                                  )
                           )
            )
```

Or shorter (For the second edit I assume that there is no space between `*` groups inside `Course` group):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(rown = match(Term, unique(Term)), .by = Course) %>% 
  mutate(astr = min(ifelse(Mark == "*", rown, Inf)), .by = Course)%>% 
  transmute(Term,
            Course,
            Group = ifelse(Mark == "*", "base", 
                           ifelse(rown<astr,
                                  paste0(astr - rown, " before"), 
                                  paste0(rown - astr, " after")
                           )
            )
  )
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
   Term Course   Group   
  <int> <chr>    <chr>   
1  1000 ABDC1101 2 before
2  1020 ABDC1101 1 before
3  1020 ABDC1101 1 before
4  1040 ABDC1101 base    
5  1040 ABDC1101 base    
6  1040 ABDC1101 base    
7  1060 ABDC1101 1 after 
8  1020 EFGH1101 1 before
9  1060 EFGH1101 base
```

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(Term = c(1000L, 1020L, 1020L, 1040L, 1040L, 1040L, 
1060L, 1020L, 1060L), Course = c("ABDC1101", "ABDC1101", "ABDC1101", 
"ABDC1101", "ABDC1101", "ABDC1101", "ABDC1101", "EFGH1101", "EFGH1101"
), Mark = c("", "", "", "*", "*", "*", "", "", "*")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```